# icedtea isn't able to open jnlp file

Tags: icedtea

I'm attempting to connect to an iDRAC 8 virtual console from Ubuntu 22.04. Icedtea is installed:

```
icedtea-netx:
  Installed: 1.8.4-1build1
  Candidate: 1.8.4-1build1
```

When clicking launch on the console link in iDRAC, a .jnlp file is downloaded. Iced tea attempts to open, however it hangs every time:

[image]

I enabled logging in the Iced Tea web console, here is that output:

```
[acoder][ITW-APPLET][WARNING_ALL][Thu Nov 02 17:41:19 EDT 2023][java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.logging.FileLog.getHeadlineHeader(FileLog.java:53)] NETX Thread# 569d5e0f, name Output controller consumer daemon writer-based impl.
System is already following XDG .cache and .config specifications
config: /home/acoder/.config/icedtea-web file exists: true
cache: /home/acoder/.cache/icedtea-web file exists:true
Ico provider registered correctly.
Loading User level properties from: file:/home/acoder/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties
WARNING: key deployment.system.cachedir has no value, setting to default value
Attempting to log into: /home/acoder/.config/icedtea-web/log/itw-javantx-2023-11-02_17:41:19.127.log
WARNING: key deployment.system.cachedir has no value, skipping
Forcing of offline set to: false
Starting security dialog thread
Using firefox's profiles file: /home/acoder/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
Found preferences file: /home/acoder/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/prefs.js
Read 523 entries from Firefox's preferences
Proceeding with jnlp
JNLP file location: /home/acoder/Downloads/viewer-5.jnlp
Using MalformedXMLParser
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
line: 2 
line: 3 <jnlp codebase="https://idrac.site.com:443" spec="1.0+" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
line: 4 <information>
line: 5   <title>Virtual Console Client</title>
line: 6   <vendor>Dell Inc.</vendor>
line: 7    <icon href="https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif" kind="splash"></icon>
line: 8    <shortcut online="true"></shortcut>
line: 9  </information>
line: 10  <application-desc main-class="com.avocent.idrac.kvm.Main">
line: 11    <argument>ip=idrac.site.com</argument>
line: 12    <argument>vm=1</argument>
line: 13    <argument>title=idrac-C4D1LH2%2C+PowerEdge+R730%2C+User%3A+root</argument>
line: 14    <argument>user=13@@54874401</argument>
line: 15    <argument>passwd=894309887</argument>
line: 16    <argument>kmport=5900</argument>
line: 17    <argument>vport=5900</argument>
line: 18    <argument>apcp=1</argument>
line: 19    <argument>reconnect=2</argument>
line: 20    <argument>chat=1</argument>
line: 21    <argument>F1=1</argument>
line: 22    <argument>custom=0</argument>
line: 23    <argument>scaling=15</argument>
line: 24    <argument>minwinheight=100</argument>
line: 25    <argument>minwinwidth=100</argument>
line: 26    <argument>videoborder=0</argument>
line: 27    <argument>version=2</argument>
line: 28  </application-desc>
line: 29  <security>
line: 30    <all-permissions></all-permissions>
line: 31  </security>
line: 32  <resources>
line: 33    <j2se version="1.6+"></j2se>
line: 34    <jar href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar" download="eager" main="true"></jar>
line: 35  </resources>
line: 36  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
line: 37    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOWin32.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 38    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLWin32.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 39  </resources>
line: 40  <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
line: 41    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOWin64.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 42    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLWin64.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 43  </resources>
line: 44  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
line: 45    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOWin64.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 46    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLWin64.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 47  </resources>
line: 48   <resources os="Linux" arch="x86">
line: 49     <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux32.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 50    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux32.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 51   </resources>
line: 52   <resources os="Linux" arch="i386">
line: 53     <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux32.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 54    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux32.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 55   </resources>
line: 56   <resources os="Linux" arch="i586">
line: 57     <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux32.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 58    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux32.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 59   </resources>
line: 60   <resources os="Linux" arch="i686">
line: 61     <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux32.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 62    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux32.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 63   </resources>
line: 64   <resources os="Linux" arch="amd64">
line: 65     <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 66    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 67   </resources>
line: 68   <resources os="Linux" arch="x86_64">
line: 69     <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 70    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 71   </resources>
line: 72   <resources os="Mac OS X" arch="x86_64">
line: 73     <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOMac64.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 74    <nativelib href="https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLMac64.jar" download="eager"></nativelib>
line: 75   </resources>
line: 76 
line: 77 </jnlp>
line: 78 

line: 79 
Homepage: null
Description: null
Jars not ready to provide attribute Application-Name
Acceptable title tag found, contains: Virtual Console Client
Acceptable vendor tag found, contains: Dell Inc.
good - your JRE - 11.0.20.1 - match requested JRE - 1.6+
UNIQUEKEY=1698961279479-1720935349-file:/home/acoder/Downloads/viewer-5.jnlp
Acquired shared lock on /tmp/acoder/netx/locks/netx_running to indicate javaws is running
Jars not ready to provide attribute Application-Name
Acceptable title tag found, contains: Virtual Console Client
Jars not ready to provide attribute Application-Name
Acceptable title tag found, contains: Virtual Console Client
call privileged method: checkSingleInstanceRunning
           arg: net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile@40e1d6ed
        result: null
Finding best URL for: https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif : DownloadOptions[use pack: false; use version: false]
All possible urls for location=https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif state=PRECONNECT CONNECTING PREDOWNLOAD PROCESSING : [https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif, https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif]
Connecting https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
Adding sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
done https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
Selecting proxy for: https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
Browser proxy option "4" (Automatic) not supported yet.
Browser selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Selecting proxy for: socket://idrac.site.com:443
Browser proxy option "4" (Automatic) not supported yet.
Browser selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Key : Keep-Alive ,Value : [timeout=60, max=199]
Key : null ,Value : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Key : Connection ,Value : [Keep-Alive]
Key : Last-Modified ,Value : [Wed, 01 Mar 2023 16:05:11 GMT]
Key : Date ,Value : [Thu, 02 Nov 2023 22:40:47 GMT]
Key : Accept-Ranges ,Value : [bytes]
Key : X-Frame-Options ,Value : [SAMEORIGIN]
Key : Strict-Transport-Security ,Value : [max-age=63072000]
Key : ETag ,Value : [1677694862]
Key : Content-Encoding ,Value : [gzip]
Key : Vary ,Value : [Accept-Encoding]
Key : Content-Length ,Value : [3720]
Key : Content-Type ,Value : [image/gif]
Disconnecting sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
Removed sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
best url for location=https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif state=PRECONNECT CONNECTING PREDOWNLOAD PROCESSING is https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif by HEAD
Connecting https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
Adding sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
done https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
isCached: remote:3720 cached:0
isCurrent:isCached false
isCurrent: https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif = false
isCached: remote:3720 cached:0
Disconnecting sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
Removed sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
Connecting https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
Adding sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
done https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
Selecting proxy for: https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
Browser proxy option "4" (Automatic) not supported yet.
Browser selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Downloading https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif using https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif (encoding : gzip) 
Downloading file: https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif into: /home/acoder/.cache/icedtea-web/cache/4/https/idrac.site.com/443/images/logo.gif
isCached: remote:3720 cached:0
isCurrent:isCached false
Extracting gzip: https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif to https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:245)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:118)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceDownloader.uncompressGzip(ResourceDownloader.java:488)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceDownloader.downloadGZipFile(ResourceDownloader.java:405)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceDownloader.downloadResource(ResourceDownloader.java:362)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceDownloader.run(ResourceDownloader.java:118)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Disconnecting sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
Removed sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
Error loading splash image: https://idrac.site.com:443/images/logo.gif
New classloader: file:/home/acoder/Downloads/viewer-5.jnlp
Finding best URL for: https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar : DownloadOptions[use pack: false; use version: false]
All possible urls for location=https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar state=PRECONNECT CONNECTING PREDOWNLOAD PROCESSING : [https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar, https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar]
Connecting https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
Adding sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
done https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
Finding best URL for: https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar : DownloadOptions[use pack: false; use version: false]
All possible urls for location=https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar state=PRECONNECT CONNECTING PREDOWNLOAD PROCESSING : [https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar, https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar]
Selecting proxy for: https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
Connecting https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar
Browser proxy option "4" (Automatic) not supported yet.
Browser selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Adding sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar
done https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar
Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Selecting proxy for: https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar
Jars not ready to provide attribute Application-Name
Browser proxy option "4" (Automatic) not supported yet.
Finding best URL for: https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar : DownloadOptions[use pack: false; use version: false]
Acceptable title tag found, contains: Virtual Console Client
All possible urls for location=https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar state=PRECONNECT CONNECTING PREDOWNLOAD PROCESSING : [https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar, https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar]
Browser selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Connecting https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar
Adding sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar
done https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar
Selecting proxy for: socket://idrac.site.com:443
Selecting proxy for: https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar
Browser proxy option "4" (Automatic) not supported yet.
Browser selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Browser proxy option "4" (Automatic) not supported yet.
Browser selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Selecting proxy for: socket://idrac.site.com:443
Browser proxy option "4" (Automatic) not supported yet.
Browser selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Key : Accept-Ranges ,Value : [bytes]
Key : X-Frame-Options ,Value : [SAMEORIGIN]
Key : Keep-Alive ,Value : [timeout=60, max=197]
Key : null ,Value : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Key : Strict-Transport-Security ,Value : [max-age=63072000]
Key : ETag ,Value : [1679110056]
Key : Connection ,Value : [Keep-Alive]
Key : Vary ,Value : [Accept-Encoding]
Key : Last-Modified ,Value : [Wed, 01 Mar 2023 16:05:12 GMT]
Key : Content-Length ,Value : [1418601]
Key : Date ,Value : [Thu, 02 Nov 2023 22:40:48 GMT]
Key : Content-Type ,Value : [application/octet-stream]
Disconnecting sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
Removed sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
best url for location=https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar state=PRECONNECT CONNECTING PREDOWNLOAD PROCESSING is https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar by HEAD
Connecting https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
Adding sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
done https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
isCurrent:isCached false
isCurrent: https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar = false
Disconnecting sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
Removed sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
Connecting https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
Adding sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
done https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
Selecting proxy for: https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVM.jar
Browser proxy option "4" (Automatic) not supported yet.
Browser selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
Key : Accept-Ranges ,Value : [bytes]
Key : X-Frame-Options ,Value : [SAMEORIGIN]
Key : Keep-Alive ,Value : [timeout=60, max=199]
Key : null ,Value : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Key : Strict-Transport-Security ,Value : [max-age=63072000]
Key : ETag ,Value : [1678797956]
Key : Connection ,Value : [Keep-Alive]
Key : Vary ,Value : [Accept-Encoding]
Key : Last-Modified ,Value : [Wed, 01 Mar 2023 16:05:12 GMT]
Key : Content-Length ,Value : [1106522]
Key : Date ,Value : [Thu, 02 Nov 2023 22:40:48 GMT]
Key : Content-Type ,Value : [application/octet-stream]
Disconnecting sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar
Removed sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar
best url for location=https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar state=PRECONNECT CONNECTING PREDOWNLOAD PROCESSING is https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar by HEAD
Connecting https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar
Adding sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar
done https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar
isCached: remote:1106522 cached:1106522
isCurrent:isCached true
isCurrent:lastModified cache:1677686712000 actual:1677686712000
isCurrent: https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar = true
Disconnecting sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar
Removed sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar
Key : Accept-Ranges ,Value : [bytes]
Key : X-Frame-Options ,Value : [SAMEORIGIN]
Key : Keep-Alive ,Value : [timeout=60, max=199]
Key : null ,Value : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Key : Strict-Transport-Security ,Value : [max-age=63072000]
Key : ETag ,Value : [1677718134]
Key : Connection ,Value : [Keep-Alive]
Key : Vary ,Value : [Accept-Encoding]
Key : Last-Modified ,Value : [Wed, 01 Mar 2023 16:05:12 GMT]
Key : Content-Length ,Value : [26696]
Key : Date ,Value : [Thu, 02 Nov 2023 22:40:48 GMT]
Key : Content-Type ,Value : [application/octet-stream]
Disconnecting sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar
Removed sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar
best url for location=https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar state=PRECONNECT CONNECTING PREDOWNLOAD PROCESSING is https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar by HEAD
Connecting https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar
Adding sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar
done https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar
isCached: remote:26696 cached:26696
isCurrent:isCached true
isCurrent:lastModified cache:1677686712000 actual:1677686712000
isCurrent: https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar = true
Disconnecting sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar
Removed sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://idrac.site.com:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar
```

If I try using the installed openjdk-19, this appears:

[image]

I've never had to set .jnlp files to be executable in the past. However, this post is more focused on icedtea.

As of now I am not able to remotely administer my iDRAC due to this issue.

What could be going on here to cause icedtea to hang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got this working by blowing out everything, then installing OpenJDK 8, followed by icedtea. Yes icedtea installs openjdk-11, but it's 8 installed beforehand that appears to work.

```
sudo apt purge icedtea*
sudo apt purge *openjdk* -y
sudo apt purge oracle-java11-* -y
sudo apt autoremove --purge -y
sudo apt update && sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo apt install icedtea*
```

Verify installation:

```
$ update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Close your browser or just restart.

Now head to your iDRAC Launch Console link and give it a try.

Comment: That sounds like ancient AWM (old white man) software - thanks for sharing