# unning a .jnlp file on Ubuntu

Tags: java

This is a part of the .jnlp script I'm trying to run.

And the ubuntu I'm using is v. 22.04.4
I tried OpenWebStart, but for some reason it would close after a few seconds showing the login.
Then I tried Icedtea, but with no luck.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/610351/1004020 , https://askubuntu.com/a/1491752/1004020 , or https://askubuntu.com/q/1394544/1004020